# Understanding the (\D\d)+ Regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I'm spending some time trying to understand the Regex terminology in Python 3 and I can't figure out how `(\D\d)+` works here.

I know that `\D` represents a nondigit character and that `\d` represents a digit character, and also that the plus sign `+` represents one or more repetitions of the preceding expression. But when I try the following code, I simply can't wrap my head around the result.

Input:

```
import re
text = "a1 b2 c3 d4e5f6"
regex = re.findall(r'(\D\d)+',text)
print(regex)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'f6']
```

Since that the regex includes a plus sign, shouldn't it also output `d4e5f6` as they are a sequence of nondigit and digit characters?

Comment: This is the difference between [capturing a repeated group and repeating a capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). (That's a better explanation than I could write up.) You can match "d4e5f6" by making the group non-capturing: `(?:\D\d)+`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/O2qyGg/1

Comment: The links provided are very useful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't directly repeating the `\D\d` subpattern with the `+`, you are repeating a *capturing group* (indicated by parentheses) that contains that subpattern.  The final match is indeed of the text `d4e5f6`, but it does so as three instances of the capturing group, each one of which overwrites the last.  And the behavior of Python's `re.findall()` in the presence of capturing groups is that it returns THEM (as a tuple, if there's more than one) instead of the overall match.

There is a newer, experimental `regex` module in Python 3.x that is capable of returning multiple matches for a single capturing group, although I'm not exactly sure how that interacts with `findall()`.  You could also write the expression as `(?:\D\d)+` - `(?:` starts a *non-capturing group*, so `findall()` will give you the entire match as you expect.

Comment: Can you clarify that sentence "it does so as three instances of the capturing group, each one of which overwrites the last" a bit more? I think you lost me there. `(a1) (b2) (c3) d4e5(f6)`?

Comment: `d4` matches the capturing group, and then `e5` matches the capturing group (replacing the previously captured text), and then `f6` matches (again replacing the previous).  You're left with only `f6` being captured, even though all six characters matched.

Comment: @jasonharper I think you're referring to overlapped with regex module? I tried with `regex.findall(r'(\D\d)+',text, overlapped=True)`, it results in `f6` as last 3 elements..